# map(parseInt) and map(parseFloat)

Tags: javascript

can any one help me out with this two in methods javaScript
`a` is resulting as `[0,NaN,0,0,0]` and `b` is resulting as `[0,0,0,0,0]`
why a is having `NaN` in `a` array?

```js
var a =new Array(5).fill('0').map(parseInt);
console.log(a);
var b =new Array(5).fill('0').map(parseFloat);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: with fill and zero, you get always a number. why `parseInt` or `parseFloat`?

Comment: Please search thoroughly before posting. Consider [this search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+map+parsefloat): It has at least three or four versions of this question on the first page. More on searching [here](/help/searching).